# How to display deals in an elegant, card-based way?

Tags: mobile, interaction-design, content, cards

I'm working on an application with deals , and I wanna know how I can display current deals in an elegant way. My current ideas are:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fi2wL5.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

I'm concerned more about the display and position of content inside the 'card'. Is this a good approach? What can be other alternatives to this one? Thanks

Comment: It all depends!

Answer (score 1):

You have two designs - well done (too many designers only create 1 design). Now test both of them with some people and see which one they prefer.

Even better, ask your developers to create both designs and when this is deployed to production, send half your customers to one design and the other half to the other for a month or two and then see which design has the most conversions.

Either of these two suggestions will give you valuable hard data about which design is best, and would be much better than opinions, either yours or from this UX community.